# Could Cultural/Epistemologial Biases Have Influenced the Evolutionary Concept of Behavioral Modernism?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, ontology, evolution, cognitive-sciences

Could orthodox conceptions of Human evolution--which rest upon the theory of *Behavioral Modernism*--be marred by cultural and epistemological biases. For example, are industrialized human populations actually more evolved than First Humans (circa 100 ka) and/or currently existing hunter-gather populations? Or might the perceived differences result from divergent values and systems of knowing?

Comment: What does this mean? _"does the concept (not to say, reality) of egalitarian democracy and an advanced technological prowess suffice to render Wilber's assertion that the earth is currently populated by human beings at a number of different evolutionary stages axiomatic? Even when those egalitarian ideals remain significantly unrealized, while the advanced technologies drive the planet toward immanent ecocide?"_

Comment: @nir, sorry, my first attempt. But if the question's not clear or concise perhaps other will assist.

Comment: To do that they need to understand what you mean in the first place; so in essence you are are saying that the question is clear; Nevertheless I fail to interpret it; it always seemed curious to me that there are two kinds of philosophers and scientists in the world; those who can make the most complicated things seem simple (Einstein, Feynman, Hume, Socrates, Descartes, etc...) and those who can make the most simple things totally unintelligible. which kind do you want to belong to?

Comment: I, too, suggest that you unwrap this a bit. It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy!! Is there any chance I might be able to persuade you to spell out a little more clearly what exactly you would like someone here to explain to you? It can also help improve the chances of getting a great answer if you share a little more here about what you might be reading that's made this an interesting or important problem to you in your study of philosophy

Comment: @Joseph Weissman - thank you, Joseph et al., appreciate your tolerance as I'm rather new to this (online communities, forums like SE). The issue I was posting about is somewhat complex (at least to me) and I was trying to qualify my question (maybe 2, interrelated) and I guess I lost folk in the set-up. My bad. Give me a little time and I'll rewrite - but I've never edited a posted question so I might need some assistance.

Comment: Please let us know if there's anything in particular we can help with! You can [edit your question here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/posts/19946/edit) if that is any use :)

Comment: @Joseph Weissman - have I succeeded in making this more accessible? If so would you release the question again? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: After some reflection I'm still a little worried about some of the way that this is formulated. I note that you've already gotten a few constructive answers... Anyway: some elements of this still seem borderline to me in terms of their philosophical interest/importance. It might be best to start in a fresh context -- by the way please feel free to ask more questions! :)

Comment: @Joseph Weissman-Thank you for the willingness to help. I believe my question(s) are now clear ...  as to _philosophical interest/importance_, that is an entirely subjective valuation. I find this philosophical issue highly relevant, if iconoclastic. I'd be willing to bet that the Yámana feel the same (if not my neighbors in Miami), and since you are a moderator I hope you do, too.

Comment: @Joseph Wiessman - after posting the above comment I noticed my question has been put on hold, again. I'm out of ideas. Got any suggestions?

Comment: At this point it might be best to start out with a new question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19968/discussion-between-little-eva-and-joseph-weissman).

Comment: @Joseph Weissman. Is this edit suitable?

Comment: Hey @LittleEva thanks, it definitely is much clearer! I started trying to revise it a little bit further but kind of ran into roadblocks. Again given the history and answers already present here it seems to me it might make the most sense to start with a new post/question? Anyway -- I'm happy to continue discussing in chat if you like. Feel free to @ me whenever it might convenient, it seems like we're in similar timezones.

Comment: But basically my thought would be to work over the history and try to bring some of the citations back for specificity's sake. --However we then run into topicality issues; in other words: the question seems to me at the core something like into *is [author] correct that contemporary human populations are more evolved than hunter-gatherers?*

Comment: So at this point it is effectively a scientific problem, more for [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution?sort=votes&pageSize=15) than us, right? --Most of my concern with reopening is that the philosophical motivations and context aren't explicitly spelled out. *What specific problem in your study of philosophy are you encountering, that you would like someone here to provide you help with or an explanation?*

Comment: @Joseph Weissman - OK. I'm starting to grasp how I need to frame the issue for this forum. I appreciate all the attention you've devoted to this - this has been frustrating for me but don't get the impression I'm angry because I'm not--though labels like rant and diatribe from commentators were irritating--I realize you moderators are people who volunteer out of love for the subject. I'm neither a philosopher by profession nor a student of that discipline, per se. I am, however, a lover of wisdom and knowledge. More to follow ...

Answer (score 3):

Although I respect Ken Wilbur and other transpersonalists, they seem to see evolution as a single track, whereas it is clearly something more complex.  It presents to us at least a tree of evolutions, and perhaps a network where traits emerge and fold back together into more complex systems than could evolve in a simple, goal-seeking manner.

We have certainly evolved adaptations that allow us to populate a broader range of the planet.  So while you may or may not want to consider local adaptations as evolution of the whole species, we do see the process of evolution at work selecting humans for different environments.  It is not clear this somehow advances the species as a whole, because they seem to take the form of selective trade-offs.  But they allowed us to migrate to areas we could not previously occupy.

In the north, for instance, light skin allowed us to move north of the tropics and still have enough Vitamin D (while letting us get more skin cancer).  And we evolved the various blood types to resist diseases more often caused by the cold (while creating certain difficulties in childbearing).  To the far north, we think we evolved fat accumulation for warmth, and when those same people moved through the far north to the middle of the Americas, we see the same mechanism adapt for long-term survival in regions with extreme seasonal variation (while making for a lot of diabetes currently).  So, this presents at least a 'tree' of adaptations that increases our flexibility.

Also, there is a good reason not to consider technology as 'evolution', since it can be lost and regained far more easily than atavism can allow physical traits to be lost and regained.  Merging these two concepts seems unwise, since they pursue different goals, an currently, to my mind, seem to be trending in opposite directions.  We are trying very hard to suspend physical evolution, and to make humans' ability to reproduce more equal, and we see the middle classes worldwide in particular producing fewer copies of their genes in the interest of promulgating more emphasis upon their 'memes'.

As they do so they mix those memes in new and interesting ways that change the memes themselves far faster than simply recombining would seem to.  I think our framing from most of advanced science, for instance, combines tropes from religions that arose far, far apart (in particle theories alone: spontaneous generation, irreducible indeterminacy, 'vibrations' as forms of matter, 'light' as the basic substance, the horror of emptiness), and generates new concepts entirely from among those combinations, that could not be foreseen in the originals or gotten by simple combination (like quantization of energy as well as matter).  I would claim this means our psychical 'evolution' is more of a network where tropes split and merge and present a less atomic model than 'memes as mental genes' allows for.

This non-linearity complicates the notion of 'levels' or 'degrees' of evolution beyond a very basic, broad scale.  And I think it is best done away with to begin with, since, wherever I have seen it as a trope, it is generally racist or classist in origin.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, jobermark. You've given me much to consider. I've since edited my original post in an effort to make it more accessible, so if you want to have another go at it, there it is. I'm hoping the rewrite is good enough to make the question active again.

Comment: One very odd take on the 'plateau' that started your consideration is Terrence McKenna's, which I elaborated here: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/18484/9166 . So I find it quite possible that this apparent 'evolutionary leap' is really a technology we came upon entirely by accident.

Comment: +1@Jobermark - @ the link, very _provocative_ stuff. McKenna is wide open; I keep him close. It's not called "TRIP"tamine for nothing, Dude. Been there, done that.

Comment: Right, and I am not going to discuss the ontological status of "See-Urchins" or "Machine Elves" or the "Mama Ayahuasca" with elbows for hips.  But both the existence of something as subtle as ayahuasca without more technology and the gap before developing symbolization need explaining.  His explanation is convenient, and he has followers.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I love Ken Wilber's "No Boundary" and his general project, I take his views as more of an attempt to unify and modernize the "perennial philosophy", rather than anything having to do with the realm usually covered by science.  As such, these two areas should not be compared.

Our techno/social level has improved from better information transmission and preservation (language, writing, global communication, etc...) and not biology.  This has allowed us to better build on what went on before and hence move forward.  I think all people are biologically capable of the same intelligence, but since advancement is a social phenomena, we should look at it from the cultural level.  Some cultures may encourage or discourage this transmission and thus their progress may be affected accordingly. How did these different cultures arise if not due to differences in biology?  Environment!  At this point, I'd recommend Jared Diamond's book [Guns Germs and Steel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel).  If nothing else, it can help build an appreciation of the interdependence between "progress" and the environment.

Having said that, if one holds that evolution is any process in which replication success is driven by change and a selection pressure, then one could look at successful societies or ideas from an evolutionary perspective. What ideas or social structures spread?  Which ones die out?  Why?  You needn't look further than the state of the world and many indigenous cultures to see this in action.

In this sense, yes, we've evolved and will continue to do so.  However, it's important not to make the mistake of assuming evolution means we're getting better, or heading towards some pre-defined state.  If we turn into a "degenerate culture", that is as much evolution as if we turn into an "enlightened" one.

Also, if you turn this idea on its head and look at concepts as the central players (rather than people or social groups), you'll get [The Meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme).

Comment: Thanks for giving that a shot. I've since edited my question to clarify. No, there seems to be no evidence of structural changes. The issue seems to rest on whether or not one accepts a distinction between First Humans and Moderns based upon behavioral variation. But I wonder if the explanation known as Behavioral Modernism isn't simply the result of differing cultural values (ontological) and a gradually increasing accumulation of knowledge concerning the natural world which is heightened within some but not all human groups?

Comment: @LittleEva Thanks for re-wording.  I'll flesh out the answer.

Comment: yes, I own Diamond's "Guns, Germs an Steel," as well as, "Collapse." _Both_ are excellent. Meanwhile, I appealed to Meta in an effort to release my OP and to elicit some new input. Please check that out.  http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/has-homo-sapiens-evolved-or-is-the-theory-of-behavioral-modernism-flawed-my-que/1763?noredirect=1#comment1985_1763